# img tag lags a bit, showing the old page image for a second or two, and then showing the new image in react

Tags: reactjs, image, lag

The page has a prev and next buttons that lets us to iterate through the pages, displaying the data in rows of cards containing a image. On click of next of prev button for first time the text fields display instantly, but the img tag lags a bit, showing the old page image for a second or two, and then showing the new image in react.

Any idea how I can prevent this? Or at least get the first image to disappear immediately?

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried which gives you issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the information that you presented, it is hard to share a solution, without us even seeing it. What I can suggest you is adding a loader to the image, so it brings you much better user experience. Try the following:

```
 class LoadableImage extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };

  render() {
    let { path, alt, onLoad, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='position-relative h-100'>
        <img
          className='img-fluid p-3'
          src={ path }
          alt={ alt }
          { ...rest }
          onLoad={ this.handleImageLoad }
        />
        { !this.state.isLoaded && (
          <div className="loader-container">
            <span className="loader text-center">
              <div> Custom loader text or animation </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.path !== this.props.path) {
      this.setState({ isLoaded: false });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handles the load of the image and executes any overriden onLoad functions if available.
   * @param {Event} e
   */
  handleImageLoad = (e) => {
    if (this.props.onLoad) {
      this.props.onLoad(e);
    }
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
    });
  };
}
```

CSS:

```
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 110;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #0083db;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap 4 dependencies, but if you don't, here are the classes bodies:

```
.position-relative {
  position: relative!important;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Usage:

```
<LoadableImage path={'/image/path'} alt='Alternative text' />
```

You could also add custom parameters to the `<img>` tag. Feel free to make your custom loader design.

Comment: Thank you @Enchew, created a custom loader as per the requirement of my app